# Alleged sketch of a proof of Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein Theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

I was thinking about the Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein Theorem (stated as by Borel):

> **Theorem.** Given two sets $A$ and $B$, if there exists a $A_1 \subseteq A$ such that $A_1 \sim B$ and that there exists a $B_1 \subseteq B$ such that $B_1 \sim A$, then $A \sim B$.

I was thinking about a proof by cases with three possible cases, i.e., (1) both $A$ and $B$ finite, (2) both $A$ and $B$ countable, and (3) $A$ and $B$ uncountable. It seems to me that, proceeding along those lines, the result obtains pretty much immediately.

However, I feel uncomfortable about this reasoning, maybe because in this alleged proof we spell out cardinality properties in the very proof. Nonetheless, I do not see where the problem lies (if there is any).

Any feedback is most welcome.

Comment: How exactly do you handle case 3?

Comment: The usual proofs handle all three cases uniformly. Unless you explain how case 3 follows “pretty much immediately”, I don’t see what’s gained.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by “stated as by Borel”?

Comment: @EricWofsey: Indeed, after a bit, I did realize I am kinda assuming that there is *one* kind of uncountability and that's where the problem lies. For the finite and countable case, does that line of reasoning actually work?

Comment: @MichaelWeiss: what was gained (if the proof worked for the uncountable case as well – but it doesn't, as I point out in my comment above) is that it is 'highly non-constructive'.

Comment: I think Borel was the first to state the theorem as such and that's how Kolmogorov and Fomin state it (but I typically did not find it stated in that fashion).

Comment: @Kolmin No, the theorem was first stated by Cantor in 1887. However, in the MacTutor archive, it says this in the bio of Bernstein: "When Cantor saw Bernstein's proof he was so impressed that he communicated it to Émile Borel and it was published in Borel's Lecons sur la théorie des fonctions in 1898."

Comment: @Kolmin You don't give any actual reasoning for case 1 or 2. However, case 2 follows basically by the definition of 'countable'. For case 1, you'd need to do a proof by induction.

Comment: @MichaelWeiss: I did not mean that Borel was the first to state the theorem. I meant that I think Borel was the first to state the problem as stated in my question (which is the same way in which Kolmogorov and Fomin state it and I did not find anywhere else).

Comment: Cantor’s or Bernstein’s statement does not differ in any essential aspect from your version. I can’t say if they used the exact same notation.

Comment: @MichaelWeiss:  Regarding the need to proceed with an inductive proof, what about this? Assume that $A$ and $B$ are both finite and proceed by contradiction by assuming that $A \not\sim B$. By assumption $A_1 \sim B$ with $A_1 \subset A$ and $B_1 \sim A$. Now, if $A_1 = A$ the contradiction follows immediately. Thus, assume that $A_1 \subset A$. Now, by assumption $B_1 \sim A$ and if $B_1 = B$ we have once more the contradiction. Hence, we have to assume that $B_1 \subset B$. But then, starting from $A_1$ wlog, we have $A_1 \sim B \supset B_1 \sim A$, with the final desired contradiction.

Comment: Needless to write in the attempt above there is a text that should **not** be there. Namely, when it is written: *"By assumption $A_1 \sim B$ with $A_1 \subset A$"*. The *"$A_1 \subset A$"* should not be there, since we work on it after.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145790/discussion-between-michael-weiss-and-kolmin).